# why isn't this returning random stuff?

Tags: mysql

EDIT AGAIN: someone posted the solution, but it has a wierd x I don't understand why the x is there but now it works!! SOMEBODY EXPLAIN !!!

EDIT: I NEED THE LAST 12 RECORDS IN TIME, I USE ID INSTEAD OF TIME BECAUSE THE LATER ONES IN TIME ALSO HAVE A BIGGER ID, I GUESS THAT DOESN"T WORK BECAUSE OF THE PRIMARY KEY THING??

here is a mysql statement

```
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_section='$section'
 ORDER BY item_id DESC, rand() LIMIT 12"
```

I need to add the DESC because I want the most recently posted item corresponding to a larger ID number.  What I want is the last 12 records, but for those 12 to be in random order. This isn't working, what gives?  I think I am just getting the latest 12 records NON-randomized.

Comment: you sort first by item_id, and only if a item id occures twice it would be sorted by rand. remove item_id DESC, and it will run.

Comment: The ORDER BY clause works the other way round!

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, what would be the use of sorting by item_id? In case random numbers are the same? Why would one care?

Comment: -1 for shouting and "SOMEBODY EXPLAIN !!!" - just keep calm. It is not healthy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn what you said into sql, you get the answer:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM items
    WHERE item_section = '$section'
    ORDER BY item_id DESC
    LIMIT 12) x
ORDER BY rand()
```

You *first* select the most recent 12 records (aliased as `x` here), *then* you order them randomly... that takes *two* queries: one nested inside the other.

Comment: i've never seen the x before, what does it mean?

Comment: THANK YOU !  XOXO HUGS AND KISSES

Comment: what the heck is that x mean?

Comment: See the [subquery syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/from-clause-subqueries.html). And it is not useful to ask one and the same question 4 times in a row.

Comment: You're welcome `*blush*` :)  The `x` is the (required) alias of the inner query. I could have used anything there - I just like using x because it's succinct. If I was writing for production, I'd probably use `first_12` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `item_id` is probably a primary key and thus the order is fully determined and `rand()` is a noop.

**EDIT**: since you probably don't care about the answer "why", what you want to do is remove `item_id DESC,` part:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_section='$section'
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 12
```

and if you want that sorted by id

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_section='$section'
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 12) AS q ORDER BY item_id;
```

and if you want randomized first 12

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_section='$section'
ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 12) AS q ORDER BY rand();
```

Comment: damn... that sounds right, too bad i don't know about the primary key or what noop means

Comment: no op means no operation, in vain. Knowing what is primary is kind of prerequisite for working with the database. The property of interest here is that it is unique.

Comment: I will look up the meaning of primary key, in the meantime it would be nice if someone posted a full correct query, but I understand if it is my responsibility to figure that out, thank you

Comment: I think it is your responsibility and it is not hard, considering the edit to my answer, but I have exactly 1.5 minutes till I go, so I can post the full query, watch out for the new edit :)

Comment: I thought you wanted random 12 records?

Comment: 12 LATEST RECORDS, RANDOMIZED

Comment: YO DUDE IT WORKS WITH THE x but not without it, just sso yo know